# Serve audio file from GCS with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, ruby-on-rails-6

I have audio files located on a private GCS bucket. I want to serve these audio files for users to listen to.

I cant use Active Storage for this as these files are created/deleted outside of my Rails application.

I could download files using [google-cloud-storage](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-storage#example) gem. It would cover authentication, file download. But if I understand correctly I can only serve files from the public directory? So do I need to download those to `Rails.public_path`?

Furthermore, I really don't want to manage these files after downloading them - caching, deleting them after some time, etc.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option in my opinion would be to use the `google-cloud-storage` gem,
since both `Google::Cloud::Storage::Bucket` and `Google::Cloud::Storage::File` have the [`#signed_url`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google-cloud-storage/0.24.0/Google/Cloud/Storage/Bucket#signed_url-instance_method) method. This way you can find the relevant file(s) that you need and create a temporary url, send the url to the client, which will be in charge of downloading the file directly.

If you don't want the client do download the file directly from Google Cloud you can just download the file from GC yourself, and use `#send_data` or `#send_file` in the controller.